# English slang translation

Tags: translation, slang

Is there a Chinese equivalent of the colloquial English term, "like a boss?" Not an  *literal* translation but an equivalent thereof.

Comment: It's quite possible that there is no "Chinese way" that matches this Internet meme. Though some people use 老大 instead of 老板.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest I can think of is:

`霸氣外露` (bà qì wài lù)

Or

`霸气侧露` Bàqì cè lù

It is a proverb but nowadays commonly used as a slang

Comment: 霸气侧露 霸氣側露 
Bàqì cè lù

Comment: very good answer, lol

Answer (score 1):

"大大" or "大神" is the slang which means the people is the master like a god.

Comment: For example,  Xi 大大?

Comment: I think calling someone "大大" is for showing the respect.

Comment: Okay, I understand where you are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind carrying some informal words and be really "native", you can say

"吊diao爆了"。

The word 吊 is a little "obscene" as it refers some male reproductive organ but it's pretty commonly used on internet.

Literally translated: "It's so big that it looks like it's gonna explode."

It actually means:"That's so cool, like a boss!"

Comment: That is not just "obscene", it's totally swear.